# Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script. Please check the requirements of 'Python' runtime

Tags: python, sql-server

Does anyone know how to fix this error below? I'm running Python in-database using SQL Server 2017.  The coding environment should have been set up properly and run code without any problems up until last week and I didn't make any changes on the SQL Server or anything.

---

**Sample code:**

```
exec sp_execute_external_script 
@language =N'Python',
@script=N'OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
print("Input data is {0}".format(InputDataSet))
', 
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT 1 as col'
```

**Error message:**

```
Msg 39012, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script. Please check the requirements of 'Python' runtime.
STDERR message(s) from external script: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .RxSerializable import RxMissingValues
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

STDERR message(s) from external script: 
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .inference import is_string_like, is_list_like
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (PY2, string_types, text_type,
ImportError: cannot import name 're_type'
```

Comment: I don't know why, but reinstalling numpy package works for me.


`pip uninstall -y numpy`
`pip install numpy`